# How can I save HTML changes I made using Internet Explorer Developer Tools in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, ie-developer-tools

I need to change the text in one promoted links tile description to a clickable hypertext. I launched IE Developer Tools F12 and went directly to HTML code to make the changes. I pressed Control-S after the change but the newly added code was discarded after I refresh the page.

Questions:

1) How do I save the changes? I can't seem to find an explicit save button.

2) If I cannot save changes in the Developer Tool window, what is another way to edit code to Promoted Links directly from SharePoint?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save the changes you make in IE Developer tools. If that were possible, anybody could make changes to virtually any website, then anarchy would definitely rule!

You will need access to your Sharepoint administration system to make any changes. The developer should be able to provide you login details.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the code resides in my team's site where I am the administrator. Could you please show me how I can save changes?